# How to see progress of tests run in NUnit on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, nunit, jenkins-plugins

I'm running tests on Jenkins using NUnit.
They take more then 2 hours to run.

I need to see the progress of the tests so if there are a lot of failed tests I can start working on them. So in a real time I want to see if a test failed or passed.

Is there a way to do it on Jenkins if I use NUnit?

To run my tests I use the next batch command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe" /xml=TestResult.xml "C:\Users\Denis\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\{myproject}\{myproject}\App.nunit"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can NUnit Console Runner report failed tests on the fly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181046/can-nunit-console-runner-report-failed-tests-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no an ability to view tests in progress but if you have time you can solve the problem in the following way:
1) create a simple plugin for nunit to dump current running test and results of previous tests into the file (then you can check it manually)
2) create a plugin for jenkins which will parse the file and show the information at the job's page