# Skip Runnning Nunit test at run time

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am new to testing as well as Nunit and facing this issue. 
We use Nunit to run our Unit tests and typically mark a test as "knownfailure" when there is an open bug for a test which has not been resolved yet. Therefore during build such tests do not cause regression to fail.
However sometimes if a test not marked as "knownfailure" and starts failing all of a sudden due to some networking or other issues, it causes the build for all other Pull Requests fail. Currently we mark this newly failing test as "knownfailure" and push again. Because of this all other developers whose Pull Requests are under review have to pull the latest master to their feature branch and push again. Which slows down the entire process and is a serious bottleneck. I am looking for a way by which this newly failing test can be Ignored or considered as a knownfailure without others having to do all the procedure I described above. To put it differently we want to simply skip the running of this test during build, until the failing test is not corrected.

We are using Nunit framework version 2.6.3.13283

Also, I know that ignoring or not running a failing test might look like defeating the whole purpose of regression testing, but in a large product where there are over 1000 tests we cant expect all of them to be passing all the time. All I mean is that until the issue is being looked after and the particular failing test gets fixed, how can we skip running the test for the time being, so that build for other Pull Requests don't fail.

I have looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095504/programatically-skip-an-nunit-test) and many other threads here, but could not find I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make NUnit stop executing tests on first failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657767/how-to-make-nunit-stop-executing-tests-on-first-failure)

Comment: Why would a unit test fail because of a "networking or some other issue?" In unit testing all external dependencies should be mocked or faked so that this situation doesn't occur.